# Validity of coulombs law for a charge in motion

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law

If there is a charge $Q$ kept firmly at rest and another charge $q$ is brought in the vicinity of $q$,it's obvious that $q$ will accelerate towards $Q$. Now,when we say that coulombs law is not accurate for moving charges and only accurate for static charges,do we mean that at position $r$ from $Q$,the force on $q$ won't be $\frac{CQq}{r^2}$? So does it mean at each instant as $r$ varies,the force $F(r)$ won't be instantaneously $\frac{CQq}{r^2}$. If not what else do we mean by when we say coulombs law is not valid for charges in motion?

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296904/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Coulomb's law accurate for moving charges?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126518/)

Comment: @BobD,their answers,as far as I understand,don't address my problem. I would much appreciate if my question is answered to the point since I believe my question is really trivial. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

"Coulombs law is not accurate for moving charges", means that is not accurate if the force exerting the charge is accelerating.  Q is at rest, so Coulomb's law does apply to the force on q.  The force on Q is more complicated because q is accelerating.
The electric field acting on Q is given by the Lienard-Wiechert electric field for an accelerating particle.  The two forces are not equal and opposite, because there is electromagnetic momentum that has to be included for conservation of momentum.